# two json files and a function into controller and a view

Tags: angularjs

I'm relatively new to Angular and got stuck with something ....

I'm trying to add a function to my controller and then to my view/html that would allow me mark a Vote `<button>` active/inactive based on the result of comparison of data from two different json files. Pseudo code would be something like this

```
if Vote exists:
    display disabled vote button with a number of existing votes
else:
    display active vote button (with a number of existing votes) and then disable it after vote has been submitted
```

that function would be checking if link.id list exists in users's vote.link/id list

link json example

```
{"description": "Lorem Ipsum", "id": 1, "resource_uri": "/api/v1/links/1/", "timestamp_added": "2015-02-15T17:22:33.300349", "url": "http://google.com/", "user": "user1"}
```

vote json example

```
{"id": 351, "resource_uri": "/api/v1/votes/351/", "timestamp_added": "2015-03-30T15:00:09.622308", "user": "user1", "vote": "up", "voted_link": "1"}
```

controller.js

```
app.controller('LinksCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('http://localhost:8001/api/v1/links/?limit=0').
    success(function(data) {
      console.log('http.get OK');
      $scope.links = data;
    });


    $http.get('http://localhost:8001/api/v1/votes/?limit=0').
    success(function(data) {
      console.log('http.get OK');
      $scope.votes = data;
    });


    $scope.sortField = 'objects.likes';
    $scope.reverse = true;



<!-- ############# LOOKING FOR HELP WITH THIS FUNCTION   ########### 

    $scope.isDisabled = function (link_id) {
        return "true if link_id is present in the list of link IDs from the votes array" );

    };
-->


    $scope.voteUp = function(id){      
    $http.post('http://localhost:8001/api/v1/votes/', {
        user: "user1", 
        voted_link: "1", 
        vote: "up"
      }).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('http.post OK');
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('http.post NOK');
      });
    };
  });
```

view.html

```
<div ng-controller="LinksCtrl">
      <tr ng-repeat="link in links.objects">
        <td>{{ link.url }}</td>
        <td>{{ link.description }}</td>
        <td><button 
              ng-disabled="isDisabled(link.id)"
              ng-click="voteUp(link.id)"
          >Vote
        </button></td>
      </tr>  
</div>
```

Code also here: https://jsfiddle.net/v6hkz9rr/7/.

Any ideas how should I be going about it?
thanks
-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your example to match your request. **check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/xPEnB4inzZxVUBsWpaw1?p=preview) out**

i replaced `$http` calls with static data for the demo

[image]

**js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('LinksCtrl', function($scope) {


  $scope.links = {
    objects: [{
      id: 1,
      url: 'https://facebook.com',
      description: 'facebook the social network',
      votes: 4
    }, {
      id: 2,
      url: 'https://google.com',
      description: 'google inc',
      votes: 10
    }]
  };


  $scope.votes = [];

  /*-- ############# LOOKING FOR HELP WITH THIS FUNCTION   ########### */
  $scope.isDisabled = function(link) {
    return $scope.votes.indexOf(link.id) >= 0;
  };


  $scope.voteUp = function(link) {
    link.votes++;
    $scope.votes.push(link.id);
  }


});
```

**html**

```
<body ng-controller="LinksCtrl">
  <div class="container">

    <h4>Links</h4>

    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            url
          </th>
          <th>
            description
          </th>
          <th>
            #
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        <tr ng-repeat="link in links.objects">
          <td>{{ link.url }}</td>
          <td>{{ link.description }}</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" ng-disabled="isDisabled(link)" ng-click="voteUp(link)">Vote ({{link.votes}})</button>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>


</body>
```

### http://plnkr.co/edit/xPEnB4inzZxVUBsWpaw1?p=preview

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Scope.$scope.isDisabled (controllers.js:41)` on this line `return $scope.votes.indexOf(link.id) >= 0;` my full controller here http://jsfiddle.net/9f7vv3nm/

Comment: @sikor, this indicates that the type of `votes` is not an array. check for the type of `votes` and comment it

Comment: `typeof $scope.votes` returns `object`. here is my exact json file (that goes to $scope.votes) http://jsfiddle.net/ujnx1zp3/. Please help :)